# How to show that $f$ is a homeormorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:(X,d) \to (Y,d')$ an inverse continuous map , X ,Y are metric spaces.

Show that $f$ is homeomorphism.

My approach:

$f$ is inverse $\implies f $ is injective and onto.

Then , $f$ is continuous $\implies f^{-1} $ is continuous.

This is all what I have to prove ? the problem looks very simple to me and I am not entirly sure about it.Thanks.

Comment: in general, inverse of a bijective continuous map is not necessarily continuous. You have to use metric spaces in your argument

Comment: For a counterexample to your proof, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562048/how-do-i-show-that-f-0-1-to-s1-ft-cos2-pi-t-sin2-pi-t-is?rq=1).

Comment: Maybe you want to ask about isometries? see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120539/every-isometry-is-a-homeomorphism)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement isn't true. Consider $i: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ given by $i (x) = x$ (identity map), where the domain $\mathbb{R}$ is taken under the discrete metric $d (x, y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = y \\ 1 & x \ne y \end{cases}$, and the range $\mathbb{R}$ is taken under the usual metric $d' (x, y) = |x - y|$. The map $i$ is clearly bijective. It is also continuous: all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, indeed, all pre-images under $i$, are open in the discrete topology. However, $i$ is not open: $i (\{ 0 \}) = \{ 0 \}$, which is not open in the usual metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$.